# Ruby: is there some sort of standardlib I need to include to have access to curtain commands?

Tags: ruby

like, I'm trying to do

```
if not Gem.available?('curb')
  puts "Please run: 'sudo gem install curb'"
  exit
end
```

but I get the following error

```
uninitialized constant Gem (NameError)
```

what am I missing?

*this is all I have in a simple .rb file.

(the command works in the commandline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `require 'rubygems'` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional wisdom is that your script should `require 'rubygems'`.

There is a school of thought which holds that [Rubygems is an environmental issue](https://gist.github.com/54177),<sup>1.</sup> and so it may be preferable to do something like:

```
$ export RUBYOPT=rubygems
```

(But probably in a shell startup file.)

---

<sup>1. See also: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page70</sup>

Comment: On my system, for example, I have `curb` installed from a Debian package, not from RubyGems. So, the OP's code would fail, even though all the dependencies are fulfilled.